# How to deal with defaults idiomatically in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following functions

```
def getHost():Option[String] = ...
def getPort():Option[Int] = ...
```

Now I would like to use defaults if these functions return None.

```
def makeURL() = {
  val host = getHost() getOrElse "localhost"
  val port = getPort() getOrElse 8080
  java.net.URL("http", host, port, "myPath")
}
```

Unfortunately this code does not look *idiomatic* in Scala. I would prefer `makeURL` to be more like a *functions composition*. How would you change `makeURL`?

Comment: Looks idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't change it. It's fine. The profit of this syntax is that it is **concise**.

Sure, you could change it with pure-mega-functional approach like this:

```
val host = getHost match {
  case Some(h) => h
  case None => "localhost"
}
```

But then you'd get four lines of code, instead of one.

Comment: Thanks but I assume I cannot change functions `getHost` and `getPort`

Comment: But you don't even need to

Comment: Depending on your version of Scala, this is going to break down into a `getOrElse` anyway, and I actually prefer the `getOrElse` readability over a case here...so, I wouldn't even change anything

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @serejja that what you've written is fine. However, if you feel like you MUST return an `Option` with a preset default:

```
 trait WithDefaults extends SomeBase{
   def defaultUrl = "localhost"

   abstract def makeURL() = withDefault(defaultUrl){ 
     super makeURL() 
   }

   protected def withDefault[A](default: A)(f: => Option[A]) = f match{
     case Some(v) => Some(v)
     case None => Some(default)
   }
 }
```

Stack a `trait` on it, then your interface never has to change and all your code will "just work" oblivious to the fact that there could be a default. Then again, this would also make you ask why it was an `Option` in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

Using `getOrElse` is already idiomatical, since you're pushing functionality instead of pulling it : instead of asking 'are you a `None`? if then do this otherwise do that' you're saying 'I want this done and if you don't have enough information use this default'.
If you're willing to use some `scalaz`, it looks a little bit nicer with the `|` operator:

```
 import scalaz._
 import Scalaz._


 def makeURL() = {
  val host = getHost() | "localhost"
  val port = getPort() | 8080
  java.net.URL("http", host, port, "myPath")
}
```